# generating a four digit list without repeats

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a four digit long list, with no repeated digits. However, the code i am running is only generating one digit, and then closing.
Can anybody see why?

```
import random

complist = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
compnum = []
userlist = []
usernum = []


def compnumber(compnum):
    for i in range(4):
        compx = random.randint(0,9)
        if compx in compnum:
            compx = 0
            return compx, compnum
        else:
            compnum.append(compx)
            compx = 0
            return compx, compnum
compnumber(compnum)
print(compnum)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have a return in your for-loop, so only one number is generated.

```
numbers = random.sample(range(10),4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

complist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
compnum = []
userlist = []
usernum = []

def compnumber(compnum):
    for i in range(4):
        compx = random.randint(0, 9)
        while compx in compnum:
            compx = random.randint(0, 9)
        compnum.append(compx)

compnumber(compnum)
print(compnum)
```

You could set a `while` condition that won't allow the `randint` to be used if it already has been added to `compnum`

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 helpin.py 
> [1, 4, 2, 3]
> [4, 2, 1, 8]
> [2, 0, 4, 1]
> [4, 6, 2, 3]
> [1, 2, 0, 9]
> [6, 4, 9, 3]
> [2, 8, 7, 0]
> [7, 5, 4, 0]
> [0, 9, 7, 3]
> [4, 9, 2, 1]
> ```

Results for 10 iterations

I would consider when defining your function to use a different variable name, not the actual variable you are passing, Ex. `def compnumber(list_to_append)`

Comment: @JacobPeck Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You are returning inside the `for-loop`
2. The loop only runs 4 times, independent of `compnum` having 4 values, so it might return a `compnum` with less than 4 values.

You can write it like this:

```
import random

complist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
compnum = []
userlist = []
usernum = []


def compnumber(compnum):
    while len(compnum) != 4:
        compx = random.randint(0, 9)
        if compx not in compnum:
            compnum.append(compx)
    return compx, compnum


compnumber(compnum)
print(compnum)
```

**Output**

```
[9, 7, 8, 2] # as an example
```

But the best way to do it is to use the [sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) function of random module, like this:

```
import random

complist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
compnum = random.sample(complist, 4)

print(compnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most Pythonic way to do it is Daniel's answer, using `sample()`.

Using loops (your approach) is also fine.

Here's my take on how to do it with a loop:

```
import random

compnum = []

def compnumber(ur_list):
    while len(ur_list) < 4:
        compx = random.randint(0,9)
        if compx not in ur_list:
            ur_list.append(compx)
    return ur_list

print(compnumber(compnum))
```